# Categories list in Piranha CMS?

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm using Piranha Core 8 with Aspnetcore 3. So far everything is going well. (I love Piranha!)
My current problem is when building a Sidebar with a list of categories.
I can't figure out how to **retrieve all categories** from the Api.

So far, I can get a list of posts, and perhaps iterate over them to collect the categories but this seems inefficient.

Any one know how to retrieve a list of all the categories from the *cshtml* pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the full list of taxonomies per Archive by calling the Api.

```
var categories = await api.GetAllCategoriesAsync(archiveId);
var tags = await api.GetAllTagsAsync(archiveId);
```

Best regards

Comment: Thanks so much. I saw that and got it working a few hours after posting.
I'm an iOS dev by trade, so without documentation I am a little lost. Visual studio's assembly browser gave me a hint.

Also, just so you know, I've looked at a bunch of dotnetcore CMS's and Piranha is by far my favourite!

Answer (score 0):

From the razor page I got it working this way :

```
    @{
        var archiveId = WebApp.CurrentPost == null ? WebApp.CurrentPage.Id : WebApp.CurrentPost.BlogId;
        var categories = await WebApp.Api.Posts.GetAllCategoriesAsync(archiveId);
        var tags = await WebApp.Api.Posts.GetAllTagsAsync(archiveId);
    }
```